# Create final table with results using intermediate tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a big table which looks like the below:

| B | C | F | P | M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B1 | C1 | F1 | P1 | M1 |
| B2 | C2 | F2 | P2 | M2 |
| B3 | C3 | F3 | P3 | M3 |
| B4 | C4 | F4 | P4 | M4 |
| B5 | C5 | F5 | P5 | M5 |
| B6 | C6 | F6 | P6 | M6 |
| ... |  | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Bn | Cn | Fn | Pn | Mn |

I would need to add to my big table n more columns, based on additional information present in multiple tables in the DB. I would need to do this in a stored procedure. Additionally, the business could request less/more columns overnight to be added based on their requirements.

The way I'm going at the moment is

```
drop table aux1
create table aux1 as select complex_logic from multiple_tables
drop table aux2
create table aux2 as select complex_logic from multiple_tables
...
drop table auxn
create table auxn as select complex_logic from multiple_tables

drop table final_results
create table final results as left join between my intial big tables and all my aux tables.
```

What would be the disadvantages of coding like this for my purpose and how could I avoid them?

I've asked a similar question in the past, but got no reply and still can't figure out what, if this is a bad practice to avoid, the alternatives would be.

Comment: Assuming your approach works, then what you are asking for is an opinion and therefore out of scope for this forum. If you have a specific issue then you'll need to articulate it and, probably, provide a lot more information e.g. if you have performance issues then you'll need to include Explain Plans, table ddl, etc.

Comment: What's the correct forum for these questions?

Comment: No idea, sorry. This forum is for asking technical questions - you probably need to find more of a discussion forum

Comment: From the little information you provided, it sounds like the data exists already, but it's across multiple tables. Your users need **reports** adding columns to one table, and possibly requesting more (or fewer) columns over time. The correct way to address that is to create **views** based on the data, and to base the reports on those views. If performance is an issue (performance of gathering all the data in a single place, that is), materialize the views. Changing the data model (base tables) for reporting purposes is a bad idea.

Comment: @mathguy The data in the first big table exists already as well (it's a construction made by me from data that already exists), so I would not modify any base tables (actually, I don't have permissions to do so). As per the materialized views: are there any limitations for them? I think they weren't allowed for queries with distinct and group by clauses.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a good idea.
If you can automatize all points that will be a great approach.

Be careful with your limitations in DataBase, including entire DB and Tablespace where you want to create your table.

Additionally, if the table is so big, you will need Partitions and Indexes, you may to manage them manually I think because I do not know the variations of each execution.

If you want to ask in some specific forum go to:
https://asktom.oracle.com